# Docker directory problem running Frigate

Tags: docker

I'm a newbie trying to install and run Frigate.  When trying the docker run command, it loads for a bit, then produces a "file not found" error message when preparing gotrtc config.

In my Docker-compose file, I have:
- /home/fred/frigate/config.yml:/config/config.yml:ro

Is the file not found referring to this line or something else?

Comment: ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: That did it.  Did not understand the procedure correctly (obviously!).  Thank you, I've been working on that one for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use docker-compose, then you `docker run` is not the correct command. You need to first change your current directory with:

```
cd /home/fred/frigate
```

or wherever the yml file is stored. Then you use the commad:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

This will read the docker-compose file and start the container.

Hope this helps